# Why does Windows not allow WinSock to be started while impersonating another user

Tags: c++, windows, winsock, impersonation, wsastartup

Using my own program or others I can't get winsock to run when calling if the process is created with CreateProcessWithLogonW or CreateProcessAsUserW. It returns this error when I create the socket:

> ```
> WSAEPROVIDERFAILEDINIT 10106
> ```
>
> Service provider failed to initialize.
>
> ```
> The requested service provider could not be loaded or initialized.
> ```
>
> This error is returned if either a
>   service provider's DLL could not be
>   loaded (LoadLibrary failed) or the
>   provider's WSPStartup or NSPStartup
>   function failed

.

However, `WSAStartup` seems to go w/o an error. Just creating the socket with WSASocket returns this.

**UPDATE:**

> Errors:
>
> LoadUserProfile: Error Code 2.
>   Can't find file specified
>
> AdjustTokenPrivs: Error Code 5. Access
>   Denied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have the Act As Operating Priv

Comment: Hello Tarquini. May I ask you how to get the operation privilege specifically?

Answer (score 9):

I encountered exactly the same problem and it was due to the environment (!): Apparently WinSock expects a valid `SystemRoot` environment variable to be set. In my case I was calling `CreateProcess()` by specifying only one environment variable specific to my app (without inheriting the caller's environment), and it was failing.

Check that you created your process by either passing `NULL` to `lpEnvironment` to inherit the caller's environment, or specify a valid `SystemRoot` environment variable.

Completely undocumented AFAIK, but it worked for me.

Comment: Not much has changed, this was a fun one in a test: 

func TestOne(t *testing.T) {
 os.Clearenv()
 _ = httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {}))
}

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the user you executed the process with isn't allowed to use the TCP/IP stack?

Try to start the application with an administrator user that is not your own account.

Comment: My account is a limited account that is creating the process that uses winsock as an admin. Both can use the TCP/IP stack. I even tried from one admin to another and it fails.

Answer (score 1):

May be you lack the required privileges to run the process as another user. Try getting the handle to the access token by a call to OpenProcessToken and add SE_IMPERSONATE_NAME by a call to AdjustTokenPrivileges and then call CreateProcessAsUserW. I have not tried this myself though.

[Code snippet in Python to do something similar with win32 calls](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/81402/)

Comment: Even when I run the process as an admin AdjustTokenPrivs return ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

Comment: Hello @0xdky. At begin I also get the `WSAEPROVIDERFAILEDINIT 10106` when call `socket()`. And after I did what you said, I get `WSASYSCALLFAILURE 10107` when call `WSAStartup()`, which doesn't return error at begin. Do you have any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Run Process Monitor on it and see if it is failing to find a file or registry key.  Perhaps the impersonated user's profile is not loaded and Winsock (or a service provider it is trying to load) is looking for something there.

Answer (score 0):

Always start WinSock near the top of main and leave it running. The need to start winsock is an accident of architecture and not germain to any problem domain anymore.