# Qtcpserver return unknown error on listen function only under debugger

Tags: c++, qt, runtime-error, qtcpserver

When I try to listen on any port with `QTcpServer`, and run app **under debugger**, I always get 'Unknown error'. When I run this program **without debugger - all seems good**.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTcpServer srv;
    bool r = srv.listen();
    qDebug() << srv.errorString();
    return r;
}
```

Later, I found [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-28787) bug report, but it's closed, and this lines, also, doesn't work:

```
bool r = srv.listen(QHostAddress("127.0.0.1")); //ok
bool r = srv.listen(QHostAddress::AnyIPv4); //ok
bool r = srv.listen(QHostAddress::AnyIPv6);// ok
bool r = srv.listeb(QHostAddress::Any); //not ok
```

I have tried disable windows firewall, run QT Creator as admin, restart computer, change port and address, search possible open ports... Nothing helps.

*P.S.*

Qt Creator 4.0.2
Qt 5.7.0 (MSVC 2013, 32 bits)
revision 47b4f2c738

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing this issue while debugging a CMake project under Visual Studio 2017.
I used following lines to debug the issue:

```
WSAData wsadata;
int startupResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsadata);
SOCKET socket = ::WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
int error = WSAGetLastError();
```

(Included `winsock2.h` and added this line to CMakeLists.txt: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ws2_32)`)

The `error` value was `10106 (WSAEPROVIDERFAILEDINIT)`. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4744539/3670437) answer stating that the `SystemRoot` environment variable was not being set.

Indeed, for some reason, while debugging CMake project in Visual Studio 2017 none of the environment variables were being passed to the program. So the `SystemRoot` environment variable was empty. I defined the environment vairable in `launch.vs.json` file and the problem is solved.

Example launch.vs.json file:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "SomeProject.exe",
      "name": "SomeProject.exe",
      "env": "PATH=${env.QT_DIR}\\bin;${env.QT_DIR}\\plugins\\platform;${env.PATH}\u0000TEMP=C:\\Users\\SomeUser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\u0000SystemRoot=C:\\Windows"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you using HostAddress::AnyIPv4 and HostAddress::AnyIPv6 and after that use all? Maybe just run with all QHostAddress::Any.